# Cache en prestashop no funciona

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop, prestashop1.7

Estoy desarrollando un modulo para prestashop 1.7.6.2 y estoy necesitando activar el cache en la pagina para que no realice mas consultas si es que ya tengo el dato que necesito, en este caso valores a cotizar a una api, este es mi codigo.

```
public function cotizarEnvio($fromPlace, $toPlace, $weight, $carrier)
    {
        $keyId = "cotizarEnvio_" . $fromPlace . "_" . str_replace(" ", "_", $toPlace) . "_" . $weight . "_" . $carrier;
        if (! \Cache::isStored($keyId))
        {
            try {
                $uri = "https://consulta.apicotizacion.io/api/v1/prices";
                $response = $this->client->get($uri, [
                    'query' => [
                        'from_place' => $fromPlace,
                        'to_place' => $toPlace,
                        'weight' => $weight,
                        'carrier' => $carrier,
                    ],
                    'headers' => [                   
                        'x-api-key' => 'APIKEYDEDB',
                    ],
                ]);

                $jsonResponse = $response->json();
                //Si no es success, devolvemos false
                if ($jsonResponse["success"] != true) return false;
                
                if (
                    array_key_exists(0, $jsonResponse["data"]) AND
                    array_key_exists("services", $jsonResponse["data"][0]) AND
                    array_key_exists(0, $jsonResponse["data"][0]["services"]) 
                    )
                    {
                        $responseToBereturned = max(array_column($jsonResponse["data"][0]["services"], "price"));
                        \Cache::store($keyId, $responseToBereturned);
                        return $responseToBereturned;
                    } else return null;
                

            } catch (RequestException $e) {
                $this->handleError($e);
            }
        } else {
            return Cache::retrieve($keyId);
        }
    }
```

mi problema parece ser que no me toma este cache `if (! \Cache::isStored($keyId))` probe reemplazando el isStored por store y tampoco me funciona.

Comment: No tiene mala pinta. Quizá se trate de alguna tontería. Te aconsejo depurar, para confirmar si las cosas que estás dando por sentadas son ciertas o no. A ver si encuentras algo. Por ejemplo, empezaría por comprobar si efectivamente `$keyId` es el mismo entre una llamada y otra.